# Making image downloaded from a URL persist (not get replaced by a new one) in NodeJS REST API

Tags: node.js, rest

I got some resources on here on how to make a Node REST API that downloads image from a given URL, the problem i'm facing is that when I download a new image it deletes the previous one and replace it. I want to make all the downloaded images save in the created folder, here's what I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const logger = require('morgan')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const Fs = require ('fs');
const Path = require ('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DB = require('./config/keys').MONGO_URI
const Pictures = require('./model/pictureSchema');
const Axios = require ('axios');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.post('/download',async(req,res)=> {
   const {img} = req.body
    // console.log(req.body)
    const url = img
    const path = Path.join(__dirname, 'files', 'model.jpg')

    const response = await Axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        responseType: 'stream'
    })

    response.data.pipe(Fs.createWriteStream(path))

    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        response.data.on('end', ()=>{
            resolve()
        })

        response.data.on('error', err =>{
            reject(err)
        })
    })
})
```

Fixed with help from @tadman:
here's the edited code, hopefully, it'll help someone else

```
app.post('/download',async(req, res)=> {
    const {img} =req.body
    regex = new RegExp('[^.]+$')
    extension = img.match(regex);
    // console.log(req.body)
    // console.log(extension)
    if(!img){
        res.json({
            message: 'please input a file link'
        })
    }
  

  else{
    const url = img
    const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'files', `${uuidv4()}.${extension}`)


const response = await Axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    responseType: 'stream'
})

response.data.pipe(Fs.createWriteStream(path))

return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    response.data.on('end', ()=>{
        resolve()
        res.status(200).json({
            message:'File download successfull'
        })

    })

    response.data.on('error', err =>{
        reject(err)
        res.status(400).json({
            message:'File download failed'
        })

    })
})
}


})
```

Comment: Please, easy on the ALL CAPS, especially in titles.

Comment: Is it being replaced because you have a fixed path for all downloads? Maybe you need to make that dynamic. You could even generate one like a UUID or something.

Comment: Thanks this actually worked, had a little problem in dynamically getting the file extension but regEx helped with that